# BibTeX author tag string limitation

Tags: bibtex, strings

I've stumbled upon a limitation within BibTeX. I have to cite [a medline entry](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21833088) which admittedly has a huge list of authors. When I take them all, LaTeX refuses to compile my document, when they're shortened by half it works flawlessly. Therefore, I assume that I have to recompile BibTeX using bigger constants.
Does anyone of you know how to do that ?
Btw I'm using the latest MacTex bundle package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the size of internal buffers is fixed at compile-time with BibTeX, which is a frequent annoyance. However, there also is the `bibtex8` binary available in most TeX distributions (including MacTeX), which, besides support for 8-bit character codes, also provides a command line interface for the size of internal data structures.

I commonly use it with the `-W` or `--wolfgang` switch, which apparently allocates all buffers in a reasonable size (as, for instance, required for or use with `biblatex` if one does not want to use the Biber backend).

So before recompiling BibTeX just give a try to `bibtex8 -W`.

Comment: Hi,
thank you very much for your answer. Bibtex8 -W gives me the following error:
Warning--you've exceeded 5000, the global-string-size, for entry Sawcer2011
while executing--line 1950 of file dinatetal.bst

How do I use biber then ?

Comment: @jan: `biber` only works with `biblatex`. So if you depend on a specific .bst stile – which seems to be the case – you cannot use `biber`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I go and get the authors list shortened.

Comment: Sorry for accepting that late but good things come to those who wait :)