# 3000 character long author list breaks bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I have a 3000 character long author list that I need to print out in full (no et al for this guys).

However this seems to complete break bibtex with weird errors and the result that my bibliography just doesn't work.

How can I circumvent this? I am guessing the problem is a 3000 character long string, but I don't understand enough of bibtex to work around this.

the reference in the `Library.bib` file is written as:

```
@article{ref12345,
  title = {title},
  journal = {Best Journal ever},
  author = {Like 100 People},
  volume = {113},
  number = {2},
  pages = {184-215},
  year  = {2015},
  publisher = {Kick-Ass Publisher},
  doi = {10.1080/00268976.2014.952696},
}
```

Bibliography is set as `\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}` and included with `\bibliography{Library}`.

Comment: if you are using a template for a paper, you probably won't be able to modify their bibtex style, I also doubt that the style would display the whole list of authors anyway. Therefore one workaround would be to shorten your author's list in you bib file and finish it with `and others`.

Comment: You could try bibtex8, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38120/bibtex-author-tag-string-limitation

Comment: @ArTourter I'm explicitly forbidden from shortening the author list...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that sadly didn't work.

Comment: @Fl.pf. - Please clarify what "that sadly didn't work" entails. E.g., do you get any warning and/or error messages from either LaTeX or BibTeX? If so, what do the messages say?

Comment: @Fl.pf. it would be best if you could provide a small complete example that demonstrates the issue. Also state what error you get from bibtex. but note you can delete all but the first couple of authors, run bibtex then edit the bbl file to put them back.

Comment: Note I had to go to a lot more than 3000 characters to break bibtex, I use over 13000 in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliography{big}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}

\end{document}
```

together with a `bib.bib` that looks like

```
@article{refa,
  title = {title},
  journal = {Best Journal ever},
  author = {Me and You},
  volume = {113},
  number = {2},
  pages = {184-215},
  year  = {2015},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}

@article{refb,
  title = {title},
  journal = {Best Journal ever},
  author = {
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, One and Person, One and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person, Two and Person, Two and
 Person Three
  },
  volume = {114},
  number = {2},
  pages = {184-215},
  year  = {2015},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
```

I get

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019)
The top-level auxiliary file: cc637.aux
The style file: apsrev4-1.bst
Database file #1: big.bib
merlin.mbs apsrev4-1.bst 2010-07-25 4.21a (PWD, AO, DPC) hacked
Control: key (0) 
Control: author (72) initials jnrlst
Control: editor formatted (1) identically to author
Control: production of article title (-1) disabled
Control: page (0) single
Control: year (1) truncated
Control: production of eprint (0) enabled
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

which isn't great however changing the author entry in the bib file to

```
 author = {Person, One and Person, Two},
```

allows latex and bibtex to run producing a bbl file with

```
\bibfield  {author} {%
  \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {O.}~\bibnamefont {Person}}%
  \ and\ %
  \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {T.}~\bibnamefont {Person}},\ %
}
```

So all you need to do then is edit the bbl file to re-add a line

```
  \bibinfo {author} {\bibfnamefont {<Intial>}~\bibnamefont {<Surname>}}, %
```

for each author you omitted.